# SVM's support vectors decision function representation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I am currently using `SVM` for my project with `'rbf'` kernel.

What i understand from the theory is that the decision function value for the support vectors must be either +1 or -1. (if i use `clf.decision_function(x)`)

But i find some support vectors, the decision function value is even `0.76, -0.88, 0.93 and so on..` (its not even closer to +1 or -1 like 0.99 nor -0.99).

What is wrong in this scenario? Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: This probably would go over better on stats.SE or datascience.SE, because you're asking about the output specific _to the support vectors_, which takes a bit more statistical understanding than just programmatic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no range limitation for the decision function value output in SVM.

> The value of the decision function for those points, will be a high positive number for high-confidence positive decisions and  have a low absolute value (near 0) for low-confidence decisions.

[Source here](https://gawron.sdsu.edu/python_for_ss/course_core/book_draft/text/linear_classifier_svm.html)

Code Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.decision_function(X))
print(clf.predict(X))
```

Output:

```
# clf.decision_function(X)
array([[ 2.21034835,  0.96227609, -0.20427163],
       [ 2.22222707,  0.84702504, -0.17843569],
       [-0.16668475,  2.22222222,  0.83335142],
       [-0.16668475,  2.22222222,  0.83335142],
       [-0.20428472,  0.96227609,  2.21036024],
       [-0.17841683,  0.84702504,  2.22221737]])

# clf.predict(X)
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

What `SVM` is interested is the `sign` of the decision. *e.g.,* if the `sign` is `negative`, the point lies (say) left of the `hyperplane`. Similarly if the sign is `positive`, the point lies right of the `hyperplane`. The value determines how far is it from the hyperplane. Therefore `-0.88` means the point is left of the `hyperplane` and having a distance `0.88`. Near the point to the hyperplane, the chances of mis-classification can be considered higher.

Have a look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function)

To quote from scikit-learn:

> the function values are proportional to the distance of the samples X
> to the separating hyperplane.

Answer (score 1):

sklearn uses *soft* margin SVMs.  From the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#mathematical-formulation):

> In general, when the problem isn’t linearly separable, the support vectors are the samples within the margin boundaries.

See also [this sklearn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_margin.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-margin-py), where depending on `C` the margin changes and more or fewer points act as support vectors.

So support vectors can have a `decision_function` score of anything from -1 to +1.  (In fact, misclassified points outside the margin will still be support vectors, and will have a score outside even that range.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/585832/232706)